# floating items in a column (bootstrap3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i im trying to convert this design into css:

[image: design]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <article class="features">
        <div class="features-icon">        
            <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="features-content">
           <h3>Branding</h3>
           <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

when i just float the icon the text takes the space under icon.
when i float both icon and content they just stack on top of each other.

Comment: can you post your css?

Answer (score 1):

use mediaobject component from bootstrap3:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media